# How to remove buzz from piezo speaker pickup?

Tags: amplifier, audio, grounding, piezo

I am using piezo speakers as pickup for my guitar. In one setup, for an amp,  I have a 25 year old Philips powerhouse aw636 stereo, which has a mic in. The problem is that when I connect the piezo to the mic in on the stereo, there is a buzz, and it goes away if I touch the negative tip of the jack.  A microphone from Philips works fine, without any hiss, but not the piezo by itself.

I was trying to remove the buzz/hiss from the setup using capacitors (trying to create grounding) but that never worked...

What can I do so that I don't have to connect my body to the jack -ve to remove the hiss?

The piezo pickups work fine without hiss when I connect them to the computer's mic in jack for amplification. The piezo in use a 35mm one.

EDIT:

One of the comments was an answer, that by Tony Stewart.

It says:

Use a large CM choke which balances the 2 wire impedance by raising CM Z while not raising differential Z.

### [image: cort ad810 with 35mm piezo speaker as pickup] [image: philips powerhouse aw636 stereo]

Comment: Did you connect tip and ring of the jack together to the one terminal of piezo and sleeve to the another?

Comment: does laptop buzz with charger on?  If you dont have one the tower is earth grounded and thats the difference with your Philips Amp. Usually a 1nF or so cap from frame or (jack -ve) to earth ground is sufficient. The problem being unbalanced high  Z mic and noisy supply..

Comment: @gabonator I'm using a direct connection from the piezo to the mono jack that goes to the stereo mic in... I have a 9v battery clip which sits in between, to act as a connector, with another clip coming on it from the 1/4 male jack side.. Think the ring, tip and sleeve applies to female 1/4 jack, i get you...

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt No, the laptop does not buzz with the charger on... I see, yes, the philips amp doesn't have a ground pin, just two pins in the plug.. But, the microphone s silent... So a 1nF cap from the -ve to ground, but what is ground here, i get that -ve is the piezo or jack's negative... The mic still works though...

Comment: Try putting a 10k resistor across the piezo and see what happens to buzz and audio quality. Use a compressor on your vocals too (in-joke LOL).

Comment: @Andyaka Same hiss and nothing else... Its quite quiet when i ground with body althoug.. LOL I still don't know why compressor is used.. I just tried it in audacity, got more mid range... Maybe i should just use a foot pump...

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Thank you, i earthed the -ve of jack to earth of wall socket, and the buzz went away as much as on touching it with my finger...

Comment: Do you have shielded mic wires>?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Yes, the microphone unit is a whole unit, factory made, it has all components shielded... If you are asking if i have microphone cable, then yes, think i have a metre with me, yes, it is shielded... Should i use that instead of the two strand ordinary wire?

Comment: Yes shielded up.

Comment: You might want to terminate the shield only at source and use a large CM choke which balances the 2 wire impedance by raising CM Z while not raising differential Z

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt TY very much.. What value would be a large CM choke of? I have power inductors with me, above 100uH, and a ring inductor around 56uH... But not a CM choke at the moment... And i don't have a bead, but have ferrite drum core...  Will go about it and update here... TY again for helping :-)

Comment: It's like a Humbucker coil except for conducted signals rather than string magnetic vibrations. If you dont know what Common Mode hum does to unbalanced signals, look it up on this site or others

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the effects of ground loop try connecting [ground loop isolator](https://www.google.sk/search?q=ground+loop+isolator) between the signal source and amplifier

Comment: Okay Thanks for that, I didn't know readily made ones were available... I still will have to look at a DIY solution for now though